# Shreve Stream Order - labels

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.3, stream-order

I am working on Shreve stream order. I made raster where is basin with rivers. I created Shreve stream order but problem is that I should put labels to map, but I don't know how (only putting text manually).

So I tried create vector from that raster and then use NVSVectorToolsSet, but I can't find this toolbox on my ArcMap 10.3 neither 10.1. It is any other way how put that labels from raster to map. It is quite big basin so I don't want put labels there manually if there is a better and faster way.

[image]

Comment: Happy to help. I'll go ahead and delete most of my previous comments to clean things up. If you do want to get the NVS tool working, I would suggest asking that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Raster to Polyline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000009000000) tool to convert your raster containing stream order values as cell/pixel values to lines with that value as an attribute. You can then label the lines using the appropriate field in the resulting attribute table, and either just show the lines over the raster or show only the labels and set the lines to no symbology if you only want labels for the raster. You can use the raster_field parameter to specify which attribute of your raster to use, or if you don't specify a field the raster cell values should show up as an attribute of the lines called Grid_code.